# django-filter don't use rawqueryset

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-filter

i have a sql,

```
SELECT
    asset.id,
    region.id as region_id,
    asset.ip,
    asset.os_type,
    asset.status,
    asset.device_type_id
FROM
    region_info AS region
    JOIN computer_info AS computer ON region.id = computer.region_id
    JOIN computer_cabinet_info AS cabinet ON computer.id = cabinet.computer_id
    JOIN asset_location_info AS location ON cabinet.id = location.cabinet_id
    JOIN asset_server_info AS asset ON location.asset_id = COALESCE ( asset.parent_id, asset.id ) 
WHERE
    asset.del_flag = 0
```

i can't use django orm, so i use raw sql. but django-filter must use queryset,because rawqueryset no .all() method.

this is my viewset:

```
from rest_framework.viewsets import GenericViewSet
from rest_framework.mixins import ListModelMixin
class RegionAssetViewSet(ListModelMixin, GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = AssetServerInfoSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filter_class = ServerFilter

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = RegionAssetListVirtual.objects.raw(region_asset_sql)
        return queryset
```

Can someone help me.

Comment: Why can't you use the ORM for that query?

Comment: I really want to use ORM, But i can't convet that sql into ORM.

Comment: That sql have "COALESCE" on join, i try to use select_related() method, but i don't know how to handle "COALESCE".